# Qt QNetworkRequest hang, but I believe I'm in an event loop

Tags: qt

I'm running Qt 4.8.1

I'm trying to use QNetworkRequest to send a request and I'm getting a 'QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication' error. I believe I'm running within an event loop.

```
void WebLoader::load()
{
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk/"));

    QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
             this, SLOT(checkForUpdateFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(checkForUpdateSlot()));
}
```

The manager->get(reply) call never returns.

This function is being called when a menu item is clicked upon. There is QWidget::event(QEvent) in its stack trace. The application is definitely running with the rest of a complex UI working.

as variations I've tried:

1. using new QNetworkAccessManager(mainWindow)  - mainWindow inherits from QMainWindow
2. using new QNetworkAccessManager(application) - application inherits from QApplication
3. calling load() from a customEvent
4. calling load() from a timer callback

[edit]

I'm now constructing the QNetworkAccessManager in the MainWindow constructor:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() : queryAnalyser(NULL)
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(managerFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

managerFinished is not being called.

I'm getting the debug IO:
'QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is MainWindow(0x28fcd0), parent's thread is QThread(0x4862828), current thread is QThread(0x7d90b70)'

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    WXApplication *a = WXApplication::getApp();

    MainWindow mainWin;

    mainWin.show();
    mainWin.checkArgs();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: manager->get(reply) should be called after QNetworkAccessManager::finished(QNetworkReply*) signal

Comment: I've now put the construction of the QNetworkAccessManager in the MainWindow Constructor:     'MainWindow::MainWindow() : queryAnalyser(NULL)
{
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(managerFinished(QNetworkReply*)));'

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your `QNetworkAccessManager` is not destroyed at the end of the method which sens the request. If it is destroyed, your request is lost since the destroyed `QNetworkAccessManager` will not be able to send the `finished()` signal to the connected slot.

This is exactly what happened in the `WebLoader::load();` method. The `manager` variable only exists during the method execution and the method will end before you will receive the reply.

What you can do is putting the `QNetworkAccessManager` in a global variable and use this global variable every time you need it :

Afile.hpp :

```
//...

#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
extern QNetworkAccessManager QNAM;

//...
```

Afile.cpp :

```
//...

#include "afile.hpp"
QNetworkAccessManager QNAM = QNetworkAccessManager();

//...
```

In your code (`WebLoader::load();` for example) :

```
//...
#include "afile.hpp"
//...
QNetworkAccessManager * manager = &QNAM;
//...
```

In requests, set an originating object to "tag" requests and to ensure that the right methods will treat the right replies :

```
void WebLoader::load()
{
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http://www.bbc.co.uk/"));
    request.setOriginatingObject(this);

    QNetworkAccessManager * manager = &QNAM;
    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(checkForUpdateFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    manager->get(request);
}

void WebLoader::checkForUpdateFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    if (reply == 0 || reply->request().originatingObject() != this)
    {
        return;
    }

    disconnect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(checkForUpdateFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    // Reply treatment

    reply->deleteLater();

    // ...
}
```

In your `MainWindow` constructor, forget the `this` if it is not necessary or use the `QNAM` global variable.